# C# - Enumerate directory for specific filetype then use each file in loop

Tags: c#, batch-file, console-application, enumeration

Essentially I'm trying to migrate my code from a batch file (.bat) to a C# console application. I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express. Primary function is a TUI based assistant for a host of command line utilities. My problem should be simple. However I have been unable to resolve it alone.

I'm stuck trying to enumerate a directory for every file of a certain extension type. While storing the path, file name & extension of current file in a variable. Then sending that information to cmd.exe for each individual file. However I can't figure out how to loop it properly. Nor do I think the code I already have is correct.

**`string patches = Directory.GetFiles(pathDir, "*.patch");`** returns ***System.String[]***

Example from the section I'm struggling to reproduce:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Variables hardcoded for the sake of example.

:: Folder containing patches
set "pathDir=C:\Main\Directory\Path\External"
:: File to apply patches on
set "varFile=C:\Main\Directory\Path\file.tmp"
:: Utility that applies patches
set "progExt=C:\Main\Directory\Path\Program.exe"
cls

:: Main loop
For /F "delims=" %%A In ( ' DIR /B /O:N /A:-D "%pathDir%\*.patch" ' ) Do (
  :: Announce current filename
  echo Patching %%A
  :: Any key to contine - Makeshift confirmation without cancel
  pause
  :: Arguments to invoke external application
  "%progExt%" "%pathDir%\%%A" "%varFile%"
:: End Loop
)
cls
```

What I have of this part in C# thus far:

```
string pathDir = @"C:\Main\Directory\Path\External";
string varFile = @"C:\Main\Directory\Path\file.tmp";
string progExt = @"C:\Main\Directory\Path\Program.exe";
string patches = Directory.GetFiles(@pathDir, "*.patch");
// Set variable for current file - Missing
string cmdDebug = "/C echo "; // enable with IF statements later
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", cmdDebug + pathDir + "&& echo " + varFile + "&& echo " + progExt + "&& echo " + patches + "&& pause");
// System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe","/C " + progExt + " " + curPatch + " " + varFile";
```

These are my includes as well:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Comment: IMHO you have forgotten what c# can do for you! you are using it to start a cmd process, what about directory services, about file class, etc. you have powerful tools under your thumb. use them.

Comment: @elzooilogico Stepping stones, I'll get there. I have forgotten a great deal. This is an old project that I'd abandoned after converting to FreeBSD & OS X primarily focusing in tk/tcl. Can't run from Windows forever though.

Comment: Got everything working & have gained a better understanding. Took a lot of intentionally breaking the code to get there. But I now have a firm grasp as to what's going on. Both answers were great & I would not have gained the insight I now have without both. I have however implemented the good doctors example in my work. As such I have marked that as the 'correct' answer. Thank you both again. I need to pick up some books & learn C# more in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not great with batch files, but am fluent in C#.  This program will find the paths of all `.patch` files in the `pathDir`, and then for each, will create a command string for each file path and start a new CMD process with the command.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

static class Program {

    static void Main()
    {
        var pathDir = @"C:\Main\Directory\Path\External";
        var varFile = @"C:\Main\Directory\Path\file.tmp";
        var progExt = @"C:\Main\Directory\Path\Program.exe";

        var commandBase = string.Format("/C echo {0} && echo {1} && echo {2} && echo ",
            pathDir, varFile, progExt);

        var commands = Directory
            .GetFiles(@pathDir, "*.patch")
            .Select(file => string.Format("{0}{1}&& pause", commandBase, file));

        foreach (var c in commands){
            Process.Start("CMD.exe", c);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure that it matches the logic of your original file though.

---

Some points worth pointing out that make this different from Dr FeelGood's response:

- Since `GetFiles` returns an array, there is no need to convert to a `List`.  A .NET `List` is basically a wrapper of `Array` that allows for resizing the collection.
- `Directory.GetFiles` returns an array of path strings, rather than `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` which returns `FileInfo` objects. `Directory` is a static class used to manipulate directories, whereas `DirectoryInfo` is an instance class where each instance represents one directory.
- If using `DirectoryInfo`/`FileInfo`, there is no need to create individual objects to encapsulate details of each file, since they are ultimately just turned into strings.  (Also, `FileInfo` is already that same abstraction.) It is more efficient to just convert straight to strings.
- The `Select` method returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which is a lazy sequence, meaning all the file paths are not immediately converted to formatted strings, they are formatted one at a time as the sequence is consumed by the `foreach` loop.  If your collection is small (maybe less than 500 items) you may not see a difference, but if it is large it can save time.
- Feeding the `IEnumerable` created by `Select` straight into the `foreach` loop avoids the creation of another `List` (`data` in the previous answer).

Comment: It's merely for explanation/elaboration as the OP states that he's newer to C#. Good points to note for the future though, just might be easier for him to understand at this point and time.

Comment: @JamesFaix

First off thank you very much for the response. This appears an elegant solution. Unfortunately I don't entirely understand it. There is also a compiler error. Line 25 states "cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'". My version of Visual C# may be dated. I see Visual C# Express is now Visual C# Community. I have dummy files/folders setup. So I just did a direct copy/paste to test.

Comment: @Dr_FeelGood Indeed I am a little new to C#. Especially in a Windows environment and dealing with file systems. Majority of my C# knowledge comes from Mono in Unity3D under OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the below to see if that works for you.

```
private void GetFiles()
{
    DirectoryInfo DIRINF = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\STAIRWAYTOHEAVEN");
    List<FileInfo> FINFO = DIRINF.GetFiles("*.extension").ToList();
    List<object> Data = new List<object>();
    foreach (FileInfo FoundFile in FINFO)
    {
        // do somthing neat here.
        var Name = FoundFile.Name; // Gets the name, MasterPlan.docx
        var Path = FoundFile.FullName; // Gets the full path C:\STAIRWAYTOHEAVE\GODSBACKUPPLANS\MasterPlan.docx
        var Extension = FoundFile.Extension; // Gets the extension .docx
        var Length = FoundFile.Length; // Used to get the file size in bytes, divide by the appropriate number to get actual size.

        // Make it into an object to store it into a list!
        var Item = new { Name = FoundFile.Name, Path = FoundFile.FullName, Size = FoundFile.Length, Extension = FoundFile.Extension };
        Data.Add(Item); // Store the item for use outside the loop.
    }
}
```

Edit: To help further, you can access the file information like thus below for your purposes of iterating through each.

```
    foreach (dynamic Obj in Data) // Access the properties via a dymanic object so there isn't a huge conversion process with propertyinfo
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c echo " + Path.GetDirectoryName(Obj.FullName) + "&& echo .....");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response. This appears to be pretty straight forward. Relatively easy to follow. Just about to give it a test.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need further explanation and I can update the answer. Keep in mind JamesFaix's points as you go forward and depending on how large the scope of files is that you intend to iterate through. This is a good starting point for sure though to help you understand and make it more efficient as you go.